# @Autowired is not working for CrudRepository

Tags: spring-boot

I have problems injecting a repository, there is no problem injecting a Service. Im injecting the repo in a service:

```
  @Service
    public class AuthorService {
        @Autowired
        private AuthorRepository repository;

        public String getAll(){return "XXXXX";}
    }
```

and the repository is:

```
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {
}
```

And my code structure is the following:

[image]
with the main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthorBookGraphqlApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthorBookGraphqlApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

the error is thrown on start:

```
Field repository in com.author.book.graphql.demo.service.AuthorService required a bean of type 'com.author.book.graphql.demo.repository.AuthorRepository' that could not be found.
```

Comment: annotated `@Repository` on `AuthorRepository`

Comment: Please add your `application.properties` and list of dependencies.

Comment: seems like the repo doesn't get created. have you tried adding `@EnableJpaRepositories` to your application class?

Answer (score 1):

Update code as below

Spring will automatically import the beans into the container and inject to dependencies with these annotations.

@Component, @Controller, @Service and @Repository - Helps to define the beans so the container is aware of them and can inject them for you with @Autowired.

@Autowired - Handles only wiring part here.

```
@Service
   public class AuthorService {

      @Autowired
       private AuthorRepository repository;

       public String getAll(){return "XXXXX";}
   }


@Repository
public interface AuthorRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {}
```

Comment: Adding `@Repository` won't add a thing. Those interfaces are detected by Spring Data and have a different way of registration.

Answer (score 0):

Before class `AuthorRepository`, Let's put more annotation `@Repository`.

Comment: Adding `@Repository` won't add a thing. Those interfaces are detected by Spring Data and have a different way of registration.